# How to redirect a page that does not exist anymore in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

When I first made my Wordpress site I didn't know it's a good idea to use slugs instead of ids in links. I had a page back then that had the address:

```
http://example.com/?page_id=50
```

When I made a template for a popular e-commerce platform in my country I included said link. A year later the site crashed and I had to rebuild it. Needless to say, the page in question was assigned with a different ID. I cannot change it on e-commerce platform (that would require thousands of individual changes - that is not an overstatement).

So, can I somehow redirect the `/?page_id=50` to a different page? The problem is that no page has this particular ID.

Is there any way? I tried .htaccess redirection but it didn't work or maybe I did something wrong.
I wrote

```
Redirect /?page_id=50 http://example.com/page-slug/
```

in .htaccess

I also tried (as suggested below):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)page_id=50($|&)
RewriteRule . http://example.com/page-slug/? [R=301,L]
```

as well as:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)page_id=50($|&)
RewriteRule . http://lucart.pl/lucart-w-radio-eska/? [R=301,L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Neither worked :(

Please help.

Comment: what did you try in htaccess that didn't work? Put that in the question so it shows you tried. Also what is the page you are wanting to redirect to?

Comment: I just edited the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please add this redirection php code at the very top of your theme header.php template before the html started:

```
$request_url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if($request_url=='http://example.com/?page_id=50'){
        wp_redirect('http://example.com/page-slug/ ');
    }
```

Comment: Awesome!
It didn't work at first but that was my fault - I forgot the PHP tags :) Thank very much, you are my hero today. Saved me a lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a query string with `Redirect`. You will need to use `mod_rewrite` and check for the `query string`.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)page_id=50($|&)
RewriteRule . http://example.com/page-slug/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: My comment with what I tried would be too long so I edited the original post. Bottom line is it didn't work :(

Comment: These rules should have been before your wordpress rules. That is why it didn't work. BTW htaccess redirection is faster than php because it read that first before executing php code.